# simplexml_load_file not loading the xml file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a trouble with simplexml_load_file.It was not loading the xml file from the specified path.File exists in the path.It was working in my local system(windows 7), but when i run this command on server system(linux) it was not working.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($folder . $del_xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);



        if  ( ! $xml)
            {
                Model_Log::error("Could not load XML file " . $folder .''. $del_xml);

            }
            else
            {
                Model_Log::info("File {$del_xml} loaded");
    }
```

Below is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<products language="gb-en" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test_brand.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gdha.library="urn:gdha.library">
<product>
<product_category_hierarchy>
<parent_category>test</parent_category>
</product_category_hierarchy>
<product_content>
<basic_information>
<product_titles>
<short_title>title</short_title>
<long_title>title123</long_title>
</product_titles>
<product_descriptions>
<short_description>test</short_description>
<long_description>test 123</long_description>
</product_descriptions>
</basic_information>
</product_content>
</product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your folder path. You may hard coded.
   Try
   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
   to get root path.
2. Check your file name. Windows server is not case sensitive. But linux is case sensitive.
3. Rename your file with lower case letters. Some linux server will change the file name to lowercase itself. So when you try to access the file from browser, it will result to 404 error.

Comment: folder path is fine, it is loading other xmls

Comment: Then check your file name. Windows server is not case sensitive. But linux is case sensitive.